# Ruby on rails how to update a record after index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive an email with a link and some GET params like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/confirmations?hash_id=jkljkjkllkjlkl&user_id=13
```

This page will show some data and two buttons: CONFIRM and CANCEL.

I get the data from my INDEX method>

```
def index
    @confirmation = Invite.joins(:user).select('invites.id, invites.horario_desde, invites.horario_hasta, invites.estado, users.email, users.nombre, users.apellido, users.telefono, invites.complejo')
    .where(:hash_id => filter_params[:hash_id],:user_id => filter_params[:user_id]).first
end
```

So,if I click on CONFIRM this confirmation should UPDATE the status to CONFIRMED. How can I pull that off?

I've created an update method in my controller:

```
def update
    if params[:commit] == 'Confirmar'
        @confirmation.estado = 'Confirmado' 
    elsif params[:commit] == 'Cancelar'
        @confirmation.estado = 'Cancelado'
    end
    if @confirmation.update
        @user = User.joins(:postulation).where(:postulation => {:id => @confirmation.postulation_id})
        UserNotifier.send_confirmation_to_user(@confirmation, @user)
    end
end
```

and in my VIEW im trying to make a form_for but here is where i get in trouble, can't make it work. My attributes don't show up.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @confirmation, url: confirmations_path(@confirmation) do |confirmation|%>
<p>Horario: de a <%= confirmation.horario_hasta %></p>
<p> Donde? <%= confirmation.complejo%></p>

<%=f.submit 'Confirmar'%>
<%=f.submit 'Cancelar'%>
<%end%>
```

My routes>

```
  get '/confirmations' => 'confirmations#index', as: 'pepe'
  post '/confirmations' => 'confirmations#update', as: 'confirmations'
```

Error:

```
undefined method `some_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x36e5800>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to build. Are you trying to build email confirmations (that users need to confirm their email address) or an invitation system or both at the same time? I would take a look at how the devise confirmable and invitable modules work especially how the routes are layed out since they have a robust and RESTful solution that is quite elegant. Just create a demo rails app and install the devise gem and add the modules as per the readme and run `rake routes`.

Comment: But the gist of it is that you should have a `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` action for confirmations. You should also use PATCH for an update action - not POST.  There also is not real reason to have a index view for confirmations unless its some kind of admin interface.